# mongoDB connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to server_ip:27017

Tags: mongodb

I bought a VPS and I want to put MongoDB server there. I connect to VPS with ssh tunnel, install MongoDB and start it. The question is, that how can I add VPS server to MongoDB Compass?
i tried to connect it with compass but it keep showing me connect EHOSTUNREACH my_vps_ip:27017

I was trying to connect via my local terminal with this command :

```
mongo --host my_vps_ip
```

but it throws me this error :

```
MongoDB shell version v4.2.19
connecting to: mongodb://my_vps_ip:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2022-07-04T15:13:34.970-0500 E  QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server my_vps_ip:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to my_vps_ip:27017 :: caused by :: No route to host :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:353:17
@(connect):2:6
2022-07-04T15:13:34.977-0500 F  -        [main] exception: connect failed
2022-07-04T15:13:34.977-0500 E  -        [main] exiting with code 1
```

here is my config file code :

```
net:
port:27017
bindIp my_vps_ip,127.0.0.1
```

it is possible to connect to my vps mongodb via compass ?

Sorry if it's lame questions, just first time using VPS and it's pretty complex to me.

Comment: Check to local firewall settings of the host.

Comment: yes it was a firewall issue , flushing the iptables + disabling the firewall (ufw)  solved my problem

Comment: Instead of entirely disabling the firewall you may only open port `tcp_27017`.